# Insert HAML into a Sinatra helper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm writing a helper for a small Sinatra app that prints some gaming cards stored as hash in an array.

Every card has this structure:

```
{ card: 'Ace', suit: :spades, value:  11 }
```

and the filename of the card image is "spades_11.jpg".

I'm writing a helper to display the cards in my view:

```
def view(hand)
  hand.each do |card|
    #print the card
  end   
end
```

I need an output like this:

```
.span2
  %img(src="/images/#{card[:suite]}_#{card[:value]}")
```

How can I insert my Haml code inside the helper block keeping the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just return the HTML directly from your helper as a string:

```
def view(hand)
  hand.map do |card|
    "<div class='span2'><img src='/images/#{card[:suite]}_#{card[:value]}'></div>"
  end.join 
end
```

The call it from your Haml with something like:

```
= view(@the_hand)
```

You could make use of the [`haml_tag` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method) which would let you write something like:

```
def view(hand)
  hand.each do |card|
    haml_tag '.span2' do
      haml_tag :img, 'src' => "/images/#{card[:suite]}_#{card[:value]}"
    end
  end   
end
```

Note that `haml_tag` writes directly to the output rather than returning a string, so you would have to use it with `-` rather than `=`:

```
- view(@the_hand)
```

or use [`capture_haml`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method).

This method means your helper depends on Haml. The first method would be usable whatever template language you used, but wouldn’t respect settings like `format` for whether to end the `img` tag with `/>`.

If you want to use pure Haml for the markup for each card (this example is simple enough to get away with helpers, but you would certainly want to do this for more complex sections) you could use a partial. Add you Haml code to a file named e.g. `view.haml`, then you can render it from the containing template, passing in the hand as a local variable:

**`view.haml`:**

```
- hand.each do |card|
  .span2
    %img(src="/images/#{card[:suite]}_#{card[:value]}")
```

**Parent template:**

```
= haml :view, :locals => {:hand => @the_hand}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a [here doc](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html)

```
def view(hand)
  hand.each do |card|
    <<-HAML
.span2
  %img(src="/images/#{card[:suite]}_#{card[:value]}")
    HAML
  end   
end
```

but note that here docs take the whitespace from the start of the line the are on, so unfortunately this will make your indentation somewhat ugly.

For anything more complicated it probably makes sense to write your haml in a separate `.haml` file.

Comment: The indentation problem should be obsolete in modern Ruby with new heredoc syntax.